# How to connect USB ports to USB controllers

Tags: linux, usb

If I run  the command:

```
ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/
```

I see that I've got 4 USB controllers. I have a lot of USB ports in my computer.  But all are connected to one USB controller.

How can I connect a USB port to another USB controller so that I can attach a USB controller to a VM?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if your hardware board design only has one controller, you pretty much cannot do anything about it; if we are talking about a desktop, you may buy an additional expansion board.

Such thoughts about hardware involve some planning, and are more appropriate when it comes to buying time, where you evaluate the hardware characteristics of the machine  according to your future needs.

As an example, when considering buying a notebook or a raspberry alike board, I google around for a few days to see the hardware characteristics the vendor is "forgetting" to talk about, and to have a feeling of what other people are saying about the shortcomings of that particular model and possible difficulties installing Linux/FreeBSD there.

Comment: I also see that i have a 4usb port hub connected to one of my controllers. Can i connect this port hub to another controller?

Comment: If the port is internal, it is the hw board design that was made in factory and such layout is a decision of the maker; what you are asking is akin to asking  "since my car has 4 wheels, can I connect two to another steering wheel?" At the end of the day the system is yours, and you are not giving us enough data, or looking yourself under the hood; if a desktop you can always open it and see if there are cables or is it all in the board

Comment: Well, i just bought a new header to attach to my internal usb pin(5x2).
How can i attach those usb ports to a controller?